# Create ContentNote on Lead with programmatically (with Zapier)

Tags: api

Almost total SFDC newb here.  I realize this question is partially about Zapier, and may not be relevant; please point me in the right direction if I am missing something obvious.

We're creating Leads in SFDC (Enterprise), via Zapier, when someone requests a quote from our website.  This works fine.

However, I'd also like to attach some information about their quote -- and I'm thinking that a `Note` is the best way to do that.

We're using the "Lightning Experience" and Zapier -> SFDC (Note) does not create anything that shows up on the UI (notes created via Zapier are showing up in the `Note` table).

If I manually create a note in SFDC, the note is going into the ContentNote table.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this via Zapier?

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: There are two SObjects here - independent of each other: `Note` (legacy object, text only, not versionable) and `ContentNote` (richtext and versionable).  It sounds like you have enabled enhanced Notes (`ContentNote`). Check your Zap to see if it has an option to create enhanced notes